# Show and hide fields on a list page (On After get current Rec)?

Tags: navision

I want to hide a field (In a list page) after I get the current Rec.

I did the following:

1.Define a globe variable "IsVisible" and set its "IncludeInDataSet" property be "yes".

2. Set the property visible of the control in the page be "IsVisible"
3. create a function SetVisible (var visible : Boolean) to set the value of the variable "IsVisible"

etc, etc,..

My only problem is that this hide function works only (On open page & Init)!! But if you try to use it on other placsses like (On after get rec) IT WONOT WORK :(

Any Idea???

Comment: What is your reasoning for selectively making the field visible?  Perhaps there is another solution that will better fit the underlying need.

Answer (score 1):

OnAfterGetRecord is run multiple times for each record after page is rendered, so it is too late to change page design. Anyway, visibility will be common to all the records, so you can calculate it only once on OnOpenPage. If you need table data to calculate visibility, you may want to use different options:

1. Copy Rec to local variable, loop through the data manually and calculate visibility.
2. If you need only data from first record, you may call IF FINDFIRST THEN ; on OnOpenPage and calculate visibility afterwards. But be aware that it will move the cursor to the first record when page is opened.
3. Last but not least, you can access Record filters in OnOpenPage trigger - if it is enough to calculate visibility, it will be the easiest way.

Comment: So still no option to do this on get rec() or on after get Rec()?

Comment: No, I am not aware of the options to change field visibility OnAfterGetRecord for List pages. And if I were to develop Windows client, I would have done it the same way, due to reasons described earlier.